# YouTube iframe shows forbidden error on blogspot page and webpage

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I am trying to show a youtube video on my webpage and Blogspot page using HTML iframe.

```
<iframe width="320" height="250" src="http://youtube.com/watch?v=Y4lqtiYLuJU"></iframe>
```

But it's giving me the following forbidden error :

```
This website does not permit its contents to be displayed in a frame, it must be opened in a new window.
```

I am getting the same error on Blogspot when posting this iframe code to my Blogspot page.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube iframes works over HTTPS

```
    <iframe width="320" height="250"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y4lqtiYLuJU">
    </iframe>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, HTTPS solved the problem, Thank you.